# How to create a module in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, php-7

I am new to Magento and trying to `create a module` in Magento 1.9 by referring to perifay. After copying the code from perifay for `controller output is not showing` in the browser. I don't know what is wrong maybe URL ,i am getting 404 page every time below is the link and code of perifay

> https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html

Comment: add your code here so that others can see the issues

Answer (score 0):

Did you cleared Cache.?If not,First clear the Cache and check again.

There are two ways to clear the cache in Magento:

**Through the Magento Admin Panel**

1. Log in to your Admin Panel account
2. Go to the System -> Cache Management section
3. Click on the Flush Magento Cache button

**Using SSH/FTP or the cPanel File Manager**

Delete the folder var/cache/ through your FTP client or using the cPanel File Manager.